# sparse checkouts in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, sparse-checkout

I'm using the Git Plugin and using the sparse checkout feature, I get the following error:

```
Command "git read-tree -mu HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Not a valid object name HEAD
```

I am using GIT version 1.8